# Decrypt AES 128 encrypted file with a key file

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes, file-encryption, decryption

I have a file which is encrypted using AES 128 and I have a key file whose size is 48 bytes. How can I decrypt the file using the key file?

The key file has no extension, I opened it in notepad and it has bizarre text.
I have IV as `0x496daa1c6914000e408c65cead91fc29`.

I don't know the cipher used for encryption but my guess is 80% for CBC.

Edit: More Info-> I am trying to decrypt an HLS stream, the `m3u8` file has this line
`#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="k/timestamp",IV=0x496daa1c6914000e408c65cead91fc29` which indicates that the file named "timestamp" is the key file, but its size is 48 bytes.

I am using Windows 10 but can switch over to Linux.

I don't know the OS used for encryption and the thing(OpenSSL,enc) that is used for encryption.

I am completely new to encryption and decryption.

Here's a link to the file
[Click Me](https://anonfiles.com/ddc795Iapf/timestamp)

Comment: What file size is the key file?

Comment: @user Size of key file is 48 bytes.

Comment: 48 bytes is strange size for an AES key.  If it's AES-128, then the key should be 16 bytes (16*8=128); or if it's AES-256, then it should be 32 bytes (32*8=256).  Is it possible that the key file that you have is armoured (i.e. protected with a password)?

Comment: Possibly a 32 byte key + 4 byte length specifier encoded in base64, but without actually seeing it there's no way to tell.

Comment: The "problem" with AES, in comparison to RSA, is that any 16 or 32 bytes of data is a valid key for AES-128/256 respectively. RSA keys on the other hand have a specific format, which makes them easy to tell apart. So unless you know the exact transformations applied to the data in the keyfile, I don't see much chance

Comment: @MechMK1 Key rotation is used

Comment: @WilfredAlmeida "Key Rotation" simply means that the encryption key is changed after a while. It has nothing to do with the task at hand.

Comment: @MechMK1 If that's the case then why is the key file 48 bytes for AES 128 encryption. I have updated the question, please check it.

Comment: Found a possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132088/how-to-decrypt-aes-128-encrypted-m3u8-video-files), but can't create dupes across sites.

Comment: @MechMK1 I have read that previously before asking here, it didn't work for me.

Comment: @user I have added link to the file. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: More Info-> I am trying to decrypt an HLS stream, the `m3u8` file has this line
>
> ```
> #EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="k/timestamp",IV=0x496daa1c6914000e408c65cead91fc29
> ```
>
> which indicates that the file named "timestamp" is the key file, but its size is 48 bytes.

[RFC8216](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216) describes how a HLS segment has to be encrypted / decrypted. In your playlist the method is `AES-128` :

- according to [section 4.2.3.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216#section-4.3.2.4), the encryption algorithm should be AES with **128-bit key** and **Cipher Block Chaining (CBC)**.
- also in [section 5.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216#section-5.1), the key file should contain 16 octets in binary format, which means the file size has to be 16 bytes, 48 bytes is definitely the wrong size. You can check the content of the key file in hex form using tools like [xxd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) ,don't open it directly by Notepad

> How can I decrypt the file using the key file?
>
> I don't know the OS used for encryption and the thing(OpenSSL,enc) that is used for encryption.

the simplest way of verification is to decrypt the file using openSSL command. (I think it is still easier than build a http server for key file and write web/mobile front-end with software packages which support HLS..... which might take more time ....)

```
openssl  aes-128-cbc  -d -K <YOUR_KEY_HEX_STRING> \
   -iv <YOUR_IV_HEX_STRING>  -in  /path/to/origin_file \
   -out /path/to/processed_file
```

Both of the segment file and initialization section file (if `fMP4` is applied) can be decrypted using the command above.

Comment: I'll need the decryption key for this. I think it's in the browser, I just need to get it somehow.